# Retrieve specific data dump from a file having many dumps in perl

Tags: perl, dump

I have appended Data dumps in an already existing dump file in perl. But using eval <> returns only one data dump. I have named the dumps as $project1, $project2 and so on. I need no retrieve $project2 from the dump file. How do i do that?
This is my data dump :

```
$project1 = {
              'projectname1' => [
                                 {
                                   'media_name' => 'Design Sync',
                                   'dssite' => 'gnb',
                                   'area' => 'qa_dap',
                                   'ldap_list' => 'list1',
                                   'replicate_key' => '2',
                                   'user_num' => '4858',
                                   'role' => '1',
                                   'prj_name' => 'DAP_Rep_Test'
                                 },
                                 {
                                   'media_name' => 'Design Sync',
                                   'dssite' => 'noi',
                                   'area' => 'qa_dap',
                                   'ldap_list' => 'list2',
                                   'replicate_key' => '2',
                                   'user_num' => '4858',
                                   'role' => '1',
                                   'prj_name' => 'TAP_Rep_Test'
                                 }
                                 ]
        };
$project2 = {
              'projectname2' => [
                                 {
                                   'media_name => 'B Sync',
                                   'dssite' => 'agr',
                                   'area' => 'qa_dap',
                                   'ldap_list' => 'list1',
                                   'replicate_key' => '2',
                                   'user_num' => '4858',
                                   'role' => '1',
                                   'prj_name' => 'DAP_Rep_Test'
                                 },
                                 {
                                   'media_name' => 'Design Sync',
                                   'dssite' => 'noi',
                                   'area' => 'qa_dap',
                                   'ldap_list' => 'list2',
                                   'replicate_key' => '2',
                                   'user_num' => '4858',
                                   'role' => '1',
                                   'prj_name' => 'DAP_Rep_Test'
                                 }
                                 ]

        };
```

How can i get project2 -> projectname2 -> media_name value for 1st brackets {}??

This is my perl code to write dump and retrieve it :

```
# Print structure to file
open my $out, '>>', 'file_dump' or die $!;
my %hash_val;
$hash_val {projectname} = $arrayref;

print {$out} Data::Dumper->Dump([\%hash_val], ["projectname"]), $/;
close $out;

# Read structure back in again
open my $in, '<', 'file_dump' or die $!;
my $data;
{
    local $/;    # slurp mode
        $data = eval <$in>;
}
close $in;
```

Comment: `$project2 -> projectname2[0]{media_name}`

Comment: Can I suggest instead of using `Data::Dumper` you may find `Storable` better suited to your needs?

Comment: Yes indeed for `Storable` and I'd look for something more infrastructural like `MongoDB` if you're planning on doing a lot of this.

Answer (score 0):

The useful thing with `Data::Dumper` is that it lets you print your data structure, which makes it a lot easier to figure out what you need to print.

`project2` has `[]` which denotes an array. In your example it's only one element, so:

```
$project2 -> projectname2[0]{media_name}
```

(as noted in the comments by a username I can't type ;p)

You could also do:

```
foreach my $thing ( @{ $project2 -> {projectname2} } } { 
    print $thing -> {media_name},"\n";
}
```

But really - it looks like you're approaching this problem from the wrong direction. `Data::Dumper` isn't well suited to data import/export. [`Storable`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) is a way to save - and load - data structures.

If doing so in such a way as to remain readable by outside programs, then it's probably worth looking at something like `JSON` or `XML` rather than `Dumper`. It's a little harder initially, but makes some much more robust and long lasting code.